# Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android

use LinearlayoutManager Refresh list sometimes this error

```
main(1)

     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

     Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{be01f66 VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1675}, adapter:com.flowsns.flow.commonui.recyclerview.SmartRecyclerAdapter@6e2a2a7, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@385354, context:com.flowsns.flow.main.activity.MainTabActivity@52b82c8

    解析原始
    1 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:5890)
    2 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:5834)
    3 android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:292)
    4 android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
    5 android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
    6 android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
    7 android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
    8 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    9 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    10 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    11 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    12 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    13 com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    14 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

this error fast has error, this list has image use glide load

Comment: fast sliding sometime has get this error

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I ended up fixing it by setting the recyclerView item animator to null

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not the animation or anything. I was calling `addview` method of **RecyclerView** in `onBindViewHolder` method (which was a really huge mistake) and somehow it was causing this error when i scroll fast. If i slowly scroll down and up it wasn't giving me errors. I fixed it by deleting addview and let the adapter populate the recyclerview as it should be. It was a rookie mistake.